# Распарсить строку разделенную запятыми

Tags: c++

Имеется ghsad:1,2,3,66,7.
Надо выделить 1 2 3 66 7. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как

Comment: Найти первую цифру, а дальше читать числа через запятую.

Comment: Именно эту строку? Строку с пятью числами, разделенными запятыми? Строку с неизвестно каким количеством чисел? Строку, в которой числе перемешаны с буквами (как у вас в ghsad1)? Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: там всегда 5 чисел разделенную запятыми, и перед первыч числом всегда будет :

Comment: Прекрасно. Значит тогда найти `:`, а дальше читать числа через запятую

Comment: но там так же может быть : и не 5 чисел. Как проверить?

Comment: Ну, берете и считаете числа после `:`. Что именно не понятно? Как вытащить отдельное число из строки?

Comment: "Там"- это где? Это строка? Или это файл? Какой признак завершения? Конец строки? Конец файла? Точка? Еще что-то? Конкретнее формулируйте.

Comment: через find я найду :, а как дальше двигаться по запятым?

Comment: Подождите... Вы пишете: 1. *там всегда 5 чисел разделенную запятыми, и перед первыч числом всегда будет :* - и тут же 2. *но там так же может быть : и не 5 чисел. Как проверить?* - вы уж решите что-то одно :)

Comment: Может получиться строка с мусором, если будет правильная, то она только с 5 числами)

Comment: От вас хотят добиться правильной постановки задачи. Точная формулировка поможет в первую очередь вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При чтении из строки - например, так:

```
char s[] = "ghsad:1,2,3,66,7";
int a,b,c,d,e;

if (sscanf(s,"%*[^:]:%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e)== 5)
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",a,b,c,d,e);
}
else puts("Wrong string");
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: ошибка: некорректное преобразование из «int» в «const char*» [-fpermissive]. Возможно потому что у меня объявлен размер char

Comment: Нате, убедитесь: https://ideone.com/0DkMwJ

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

int main(void) {
   string s("ghsad:1,2,3,66,7");
   vector<int> v;
   int i;

   stringstream ss(s.substr(s.find(':') + 1));
   while (ss >> i) {
      v.push_back(i); // если дальше нужно оперировать полученными значениями
      cout << i << " ";

      if (ss.peek() == ',') ss.ignore();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Если просто "выпилить" числа из строки, то есть на выходе получить "123667", можно, например, поступить так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::remove_if;
using std::string;

struct NaN {
   bool operator()(const char c) { return c != ' ' && !isdigit(c); }
};

int main(void) {
   string s("ghsad:1,2,3,66,7");
   NaN nan;

   string nums(s.begin(), remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), nan));
   cout << nums << endl;

   return 0;
}
```